# How would I make a program to monitor another system's vitals with a remote connection?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, monitoring, rdp

I'm looking to write a custom program in VB.NET / C++ / C# that would allow me to monitor a system's vitals over a Remote Desktop Connection.

I'm only looking for tips on how to implement a connection like this in code (eg. is it just a simple object or call to a WScript function? or is it much more sophisticated?). As to the specifics of operation after making the connection, I have that figured out based on another program which shares some similar features.

I would definitely look on Google and self-teach this, but I don't even know where to begin / what to search for. Some advice into this would be amazing, thanks!

**EDIT:** This doesn't have to go through an RDP connection, I'm definitely looking for better ways. Reason I mention RDP is because I currently do this manually over an RDP connection, but I don't wanna have to constantly open the window.

Comment: RDP is definitely not the right protocol for this.  Perhaps you are thinking of RPC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the RDP protocol is the right solution for this. Other mechanisms were invented for this, such as [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

WMI is a scriptable interface that allows you to query the local or remote computer's information. You can use your tool of choice - C#, VBScript, or my personal preference - Powershell. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377) is an example of how to get all of the processes on a remote machine.

**EDIT**:

> This doesn't have to go through an RDP connection, I'm definitely looking for better ways. Reason I mention RDP is because I currently do this manually over an RDP connection, but I don't wanna have to constantly open the window.

Then ignore everything below the line. Really.

---

The RDP protocol is very specialized for sharing specific resources. Namely the screen, disks, clipboard, printer, ports, and sound. That's it for what's out-of-the-box. The *best* thing you could possibly do is occasionally monitor the contents of a file with the RDP protocol - and it is cumbersome and slow.

I'd encourage you to look at alternative solutions like WMI instead.

That said, it is [*possible*](http://singularitylaw.com/technology-law/just-because-you-can-doesn%E2%80%99t-mean-you-should) to do this with RDP's support for Virtual Channels. You could [create a scriptable virtual channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to accomplish this (which is no easy feat). You would have to write a client and server. Your server side functionality would report the information you are interested in monitoring, and the client side would receive it. Again, I would stress that this is not the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely look into that. This is what I'm missing, a mentor who knows things, lol. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but thanks a lot!